# How to make a function in bash that insert a new filename between others?

Tags: bash, rename, function

Suppose, I have a directory called `Titlepage` that have many files named `titlepage_1.pdf`, `titlepage_2.pdf` ... `titlepage_n.pdf` and their `tex` files also. I have a bash function that alter two filenames.(e.g. `$alterpdf 2 3` this command swap filename `titlepage_2.pdf` to `titlepage_3.pdf`. And does same thing for the corresponding `tex` files also.)

```
function swap(){ mv $1 $1._tmp && mv $2 $1 && mv $1._tmp $2; }
function alterpdf(){ swap titlepage_$1.pdf titlepage_$2.pdf; swap titlepage_$1.tex titlepage_$2.tex; }
```

Now, I want a function(e.g, `filepush new.pdf 2 3`) that can insert `new.pdf` inside `titlepage_2.pdf` and `titlepage_3.pdf` with the name `titlepage_3.pdf`. And next files's number is increased. `titlepage_3.pdf` to `titlepage_4.pdf` `titlepage_4.pdf` to `titlepage_5.pdf` and so on.

There also a `.tex` file for all pdf in that directory.

**Edit**
I want to implement follows-

```
Titlepage$ ls
titlepage_1.tex titlepage_1.pdf titlepage_2.tex titlepage_2.pdf titlepage_3.tex titlepage_3.pdf
Titlepage$ vim new.tex
Titlepage$ pdflatex new.tex
Titlepage$ ls
new.pdf new.tex titlepage_1.tex titlepage_1.pdf titlepage_2.tex titlepage_2.pdf titlepage_3.tex 
titlepage_3.pdf
Titlepage$ push new.pdf 2 3
Titlepage$ ls
titlepage_1.tex titlepage_1.pdf titlepage_2.tex titlepage_2.pdf titlepage_3.tex titlepage_3.pdf titlepage_4.tex titlepage_4.pdf
```

**Edit**
proposed solution

```
$ls *.pdf|grep -Eo [0-9]+|sort -n
```

This results the index of the files. Starting from tail increment each index adding 1 for each file up to the insertion point(2nd argument of `push`). Then rename the target file(`new.pdf`) to `titlepage_3rd_argement_of_push.pdf`

Comment: What is the relevance of the .tex files? They're not mentioned in the renames to that point. Do they need to be renamed?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes. I edited my question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's a script that does something like what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

NEWFILES=${1}
INSERT_IDX=${2}
PREFIX="titlepage_"

# just in case
prefixnum=${filebase//[^0-9]/}
case $prefixnum in
  (*[![:blank:]]*) echo "invalid prefix, contains numbers"; exit 1;;
esac

# check input arguments
if [ ! $# -eq 2 ];
then
  echo "USAGE: insert.sh <newfiles> <insertion_index>"
  echo 'example: insert.sh "new.pdf new.tex" 2'
  exit 1
fi

## process infiles
for infile in ${NEWFILES}
do
  ext=${infile##*.}
  for file in $(ls -1 ${PREFIX}[0-9]*.${ext} | sort -rV)
  do

      filebase=${file%.*}
      number=${filebase//[^0-9]/}
      numberless=${filebase//[0-9]/}

      if [ "${numberless}${number}.${ext}" != "${file}" ];
      then
        echo "invalid file ${file}"
        echo "${numberless}${number}.${ext}" "${file}"
        exit 1
      fi

      if [ ${number} -ge ${INSERT_IDX} ]
      then
          echo "$file" "${numberless}$((${number} + 1))".$ext
          mv "$file" "${numberless}$((${number} + 1))".$ext
      else
        echo ${file}
      fi
  done
  echo "${infile}"  "${PREFIX}${INSERT_IDX}.${ext}"
  mv "${infile}"  "${PREFIX}${INSERT_IDX}.${ext}"
done
```

Comment: Check your script urgently. There is a great mistake, but easy to solve.  
`$./insert.sh "delete.pdf delete.tex" 2 \\
\titlepage_1.pdf\\
titlepage_2.pdf titlepage_3.pdf
titlepage_3.pdf titlepage_4.pdf\\
titlepage_4.pdf titlepage_5.pdf\\
delete.pdf titlepage_2.pdf \\titlepage_1.tex
titlepage_2.tex titlepage_3.tex
titlepage_3.tex titlepage_4.tex
titlepage_4.tex titlepage_5.tex`

Comment: That means finally only `titlepage_5.tex and titlepage_5.pdf` and befor index 3.

Comment: That was a bad bug, thanks for catching it. I reversed the sort order, which should get rid of that problem.

Comment: Yes, now it works. The script is large enough. If you can minimize the script size it is helpful to other to understand what you want to do easily.

Comment: I don't fell the necessity of first `if(...........invalid file.......)` block inside the `for` loop. I guess `if [ "${numberless}${number}.${ext}" != "${file}" ];` is false all time.

Comment: `insert.sh "new.pdf new.tex" 2` it can be written as `insert.sh new 2` and your script should add the extension `.pdf` and `.tex`. no need to type same name twice.

Answer (score 0):

> that can insert `new.pdf` inside `titlepage_2.pdf` and `titlepage_3.pdf`

So to clarify, you want to be able to sandwich new.pdf between to the two titlepage files, and produce a new file, titlepage_3.pdf, and move the original titlepage_3.pdf to a titlepage_4.pdf, and increment the number of the remaining pdf files with similar names?

In other words, we want to be left with a new list, where the new titlepage_3.pdf now contains the pages in titlepage_2.pdf, then the pages in new.pdf, then the pages in titlepage_3.pdf? There are several ways to [concatenate pdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf) you could use for this. For incrementing the numbers, I would recommend doing that before the concatenation step, using perl-style regex and the `rename` command.

For the .tex files, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25713/how-do-i-combine-several-tex-files-into-one) might have useful information on how to concatenate tex files.

Comment: You don't understand my question. I don't say inserting `new.pdf` in a pdf file. I want to insert this inside the filesystem.

Comment: I edited my question again. See that.

Comment: You can delete this, as you posted a solution.